# How to send a user different files based on selection via email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, user-interface, frontend

I am building a web app in which a user can choose to get some digital files(photos, videos, etc. via email)

let's say item 1,2,...,n.

The user can either pick only one item or a combination between them. My thought was to send the download link for each item, however the more items the user needs, the more unpractical it gets.

Is there a more suitable way to achieve this?

Comment: Create a zip file on the server side and send a link to that?

Comment: thank you for the advice. I will try to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can set parameter in that link, like ?values="1,2,3,4,5..."
And by this values, compress that files, and give just compressed one.

Comment: Good idea! I will try to implement it, thank you.